# recursive grep does not list matches from some files

Tags: bash, grep, recursive

I am using GNU grep 3.4 to find scripts that contain a certain pattern. For this, I call `grep` recursively like so

```
grep -rin . -e "pattern"
```

The pattern is just a word, no regular expression. The weird thing is that the output does not list occurrences in some files which definitely contain the string.

I have tried opening these files in `vim` and searching there using `/pattern` and it finds the pattern. The encoding is displayed in `vim` as `[dos:utf-8:]`. When I copy the line and write it to a new file, the above `grep` command lists it correctly.

Why doesn't `grep` list the original file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem (with the help of another answer). The files 'grep' did not show any output for were not actually `utf-8` encoded, but `utf-16be`. I learned this using hexdump (credits to @RedGrittyBrick):

```
hd file_for_which_grep_works_as_expected.txt
```

yielded

```
00000000  20 20 20 20 50 61 74 74  65 72 6e 0a              |    Pattern.|
0000000c
```

whereas

```
hd file_for_which_grep_fails.txt
```

returned

```
00000000  fe ff 00 50 00 61 00 74  00 74 00 65 00 72 00 6e  |...P.a.t.t.e.r.n|
00000010  00 0a                                             |..|
00000012
```

So, double-checking the encoding with

```
file -i file_for_which_grep_fails.txt
```

identified it as `text/plain; charset=utf-16be`.

I failed to recognize that the `utf-8` shown by `vim` were actually the *buffer* encoding, not the *file* encoding. Executing `:set fileencoding` in `vim` also correctly displayed `fileencoding=utf-16` (found here https://superuser.com/a/28783/1210682).

So, the problem is that my `grep` does not work on `utf-16` encoded files. This has already been described here: https://superuser.com/a/231471/1210682. However, the remedy of converting `utf-16` files to `utf-8` before `grep` does not work when I use it recursively, as I don't know beforehand which files may be `utf-8` and which `utf-16` and a am searching through a lot of files.

There are different solutions, two of which I am going to shortly describe here:

1. A *quick-and-dirty* solution that worked for me was to expand the search pattern to include one that would match the `utf-16` version and search for one of both patterns:

   ```
   grep -riPa . -e "pattern|p.a.t.t.e.r.n."
   ```

   This is of course very limited in terms of possible patterns.
2. There are alternatives to `grep` like `ugrep` or `ripgrep` that (among other things) can handle `utf-16` files. I ended up using `ripgrep` which is available in the standard Ubuntu package repositories from 18.04 on:

   ```
   rg -i "pattern"
   ```

There is a great discussion on alternatives here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752913/grepping-binary-files-and-utf16, among them an interesting approach attempting to convert the search pattern to `utf-16` and feeding that to `grep`. However, I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Grep (or at least older ones) don't understand UTF8. So composed characters, hyphenation points or other invisible data might discourage grep.

Grep is also affected by the values of $LC_ALL, $LC_CTYPE and $LANG.

Use vim to save a few lines around a word that grep failed to find then make a hexdump of that tiny example file. You'll probably see why grep failed

You can also use vim commands (`ga`, `g8` etc) to examine characters but a hex dump may be clearer

Comment: Thank you, that was great advice. I found that the problem was not invisible data, but that the files in question were in fact `utf-16` encoded. I am adding a detailed answer with my findings.

Comment: Since I am new: Would it be appropriate if I accepted my own answer? Yours helped me to find it, but the one I build on top of that has the complete answer. Thank you!

Comment: @buddemat: it is perfectly OK to accept your own answer.